# I want to store this data in array this data is recieved from file,

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to split the content of a text file by `;` and `:`:

> #STA:00007;TM:01/30/2016,13:48:03;

Desired output:

```
STA        TM
00007      01/30/2016,13:48:03
```

Comment: use `preg_match('~STA:(\d+);TM:([^;]*)~', $str)`

Answer (score 0):

This should separate your values.

```
preg_match('/^#STA:(\d+);TM:([\d\/:,]+);$/', '#STA:00007;TM:01/30/2016,13:48:03;', $matches);
$sta = $matches[1];
$tm = $matches[2];
```

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/zH7gL9/1
PHP Demo: https://eval.in/515351

If that part is in the middle of a string take out the anchors `^$`.

`\d` is a number `0-9`.
`+` is a quantifer meaning 1 or more of the preceding character/group/class.
`[]` is a character meaning the characters inside are allowed.
`^$` are anchors, matching the start and end of the string.
`/`s are delimiters.
`()` are capture groups (what is inside is captured).
Everything else in that regex is literal.